# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart

I am trying to get JSON response but I am getting this error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>
```

here is my code:

```
Future<List> loadFriendParties (String id) async {
    //TODO change userId
    var request = await EndPoints.getUserInterest(id);
    print(request.body);
    print(request.statusCode);
    if (request.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(request.body)['data'] ?? [];
    }
    return [];
  }
```

and

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: myFriendPartiesLoader = loadFriendParties(element['id']),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
         print('snapshot: ${snapshot.data}');
         print('snapshot2: ${snapshot}');
```

above prints are giving me this:

```
snapshot: null
snapshot2: AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>(ConnectionState.done, null, type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'
```

and this is my JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "intrested": [
            {
                "event_name": "Karaoke",
                "city": "Warszawa
                "description": "text",
            },
            {
                "event_name": "PAPUGOWE",
                "city": "Toruń",
                "description": "text",
            }
        ],
        "participate": [],
        "be_today": [
            {
                "name": "Ryba Piła",
                "city": "Gdańsk",
                "description": "text",
            },
            {
                "name": "Moon Club",
                "city": "Toruń",
                "description": "text.",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to handle  response from JSON in this case properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<List> loadFriendParties (String id) async {
    //TODO change userId
    var request = await EndPoints.getUserInterest(id);
    print(request.body);
    print(request.statusCode);
    if (request.statusCode == 200) {
    
     Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(request.body)['data'];
     //then return what you want here
     
    }
    return [];
  }
```

Comment: snapshot is now returning json data, but I got this error now:
```type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast```

I changed my function from ```Future<List>``` to ```Future<Object>``` to return ```json``` variable

Comment: @KarolWiśniewski are you using any model class,if yes can u share

Comment: No, I don't have that

Comment: @KarolWiśniewski you should create one if you want to display data in your widget.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).